# Regex to match an extension

Tags: regex

I use this regex

```
[^\/\.]+$
```

to match `.php`

```
http://www.demo.com/profiles-forum/linda-blair.php
```

but it match only `php`. How canI include also dot?

Comment: Try this: `\.[^\/\.]+$`.

Comment: @MátéJuhász and if I wish  to extract only `linda-blair` between `/` and `.php` need I to write `[^\/]^+$`?

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa-TUpSx1JA) plz watch this i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need only file name try this (for between / and .php)

```
([^\/]*)\.[^.]*$
```

source : [A Regex FileName without extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671522/regex-capture-filename-from-url-without-file-extension)

Or use **PHP** `preg_match_all` function and store all results in a variable

```
<?php
$sites = array(
"http://www.demo.com/profiles-forum/linda.php",
"http://www.demo.com/profiles-forum/linda-blair.php",
"http://www.demo.com/profiles-forum/linda123_example.php");
foreach ($sites as $site){
preg_match_all('/(^http:\/\/www.demo.com\/profiles-forum\/)(.*).php/',$site,$res);
print_r($res[2][0]."<br>");
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
linda
linda-blair
linda123_example
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want:

```
[^/]+(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

that is returning the filename **without** extension.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/pJOfEu/1)

---

If you want to match the filename **with** the extension, use:

```
[^/]+\.[^.]+$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/GLaEcN/1)

Comment: thank you very much for your solution